# What is the origin of en vouloir?

Tags: sens

I met an expression **en vouloir** in two sentences coming from Harry Potter and Le Petit Prince:

> Il ne pouvait pas lui **en vouloir**.
>
> Il ne faut pas leur **en vouloir**.

When I found out that it means *to blame* someone, the use of the verb **vouloir** felt very strange and I wonder how this expression came to be. Why a verb meaning *to want* creates an expression like that?

Is there any approximated, or common sense translation of this expression?

Comment: A similar use of “want” in Eng is found in “[Do] [You want a part of me?](https://books.google.com/books?id=v-5BPbPfzBAC&pg=PT28&dq=%22you+want+a+part+of+me?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj68Mzgn4rQAhUlxYMKHS3rA5oQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22you%20want%20a%20part%20of%20me%3F%22&f=false)” and “[Do] [You want a piece of me?](https://books.google.com/books?id=e8UvDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22you+want+a+piece+of+me?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoan5pYrQAhUE6oMKHd5fC-oQ6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22you%20want%20a%20piece%20of%20me%3F%22&f=false) (They even contain the “partitif” notion often captured in French by “en.”)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [en vouloir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_vouloir) has not only the meaning to blame someone :

> - Avoir contre quelqu’un un sentiment de malveillance. (To have against someone the will to harm)
> - Attaquer, tenter de nuire à quelqu’un. (To want to attack or to be detrimental to)
> - Avoir une rancune vis-à-vis de quelqu’un. (To have hard feelings or grudge)
> - Avoir quelque prétention sur une personne, sur une chose, en avoir quelque désir. (To desire)
> - Avoir du regret, du repentir. (To regret)

And it can also means

> Être très déterminé, très motivé. (To be motivated, determinated)

---

To help you to understand, you have to place yourself in situation:
*Something happened, probably caused by someone and you* :

- want revenge / to ask for compensation (3 firsts meanings);
- want to have / get it back (to desire);
- want to have done differently (to regret).

→ You want to have something from this person. (excuses, goods, feelings)

→ You are refusing the current situation and want reality to change.

You can look at the [reverse translation](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/reverse/en%20vouloir) to have more traductions.

Comment: Thanks, there's one thing that I want to ask you: does en vouloir have the following meanings mixed together all at once, or does en vouloir mean slightly different things in different contexts?

Will I be able to differentiate between the 5 meanings that you gave from the context of a sentence?

Comment: @Camille No, there is one meaning by context. You could be able to differentiate them by the context, but it may be hard. Look at examples in the first link I give, you will see that the 3 first meanings may be hard to differentiate because they are all holding the `be offended - ask compensation` situation, with different degrees of anger.

Answer (score 1):

I think the literal translation might sound a touch unidiomatic, but not terribly strange.

> He could not **want** anything against him.

But in English, I would say the idiomatic expression that most closely approximates this usage is *hold* instead of *want*.

> He could not **hold** anything against him.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it came from « vouloir du mal à quelqu’un » which is shortened to « en vouloir à quelqu’un » long ago

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language Stack Exchange. I wonder if you have some sources that back up what you say and that would tell us when "long ago" was exactly. That would greatly improve the quality of your answer.